# Limit character input in jtextfield or area

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentfilter

I'm trying to limit the char input on multiple jtextfield. The two fields has different char limit and at the same time they cannot accept white space as their 1st char... for example the 1st field has only 5 char limit then the 2nd field has 10char limit.. I'm stuck on this problem here is the code that I am using:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

 public class Restriction {

    public Restriction() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Restriction();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        GridBagConstraints Cons = new GridBagConstraints();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextField jtf = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField jtf2 = new JTextField(20);
        //add filter to document
        ((AbstractDocument) jtf.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new MyDocumentFilter());
        MyDocumentFilter.charLimit(5);
        ((AbstractDocument) jtf2.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new MyDocumentFilter());
        MyDocumentFilter.charLimit(10);
        Cons.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(jtf, Cons);
        Cons.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(jtf2,Cons);  
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    static int Limit;

    public static void charLimit(int Limitation){
        Limit = Limitation;
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int i, int i1, String string, AttributeSet as) throws BadLocationException {
        //we want standard behavior if we are not placing space at start of JTextField
        //or if we are placing text at start of JTextField but first character is not whitespace
        if ( i!=0 && i< Limit || ( i==0 && !Character.isWhitespace(string.charAt(0)) ) ){
            super.replace(fb, i, i1, string, as);
        }else{
            System.out.println("no spaces allowed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int i, int i1) throws BadLocationException {
        super.remove(fb, i, i1);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int i, String string, AttributeSet as) throws BadLocationException {
        super.insertString(fb, i, string, as);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `javax.swing.text.Document`

You can initiate it like:

```
 public static Document createTextDocument(int maxLength){
        return new TextDocument(maxLength);
    }

...

Document document = createTextDocument(5); // limit to 5 chars
textField1.setDocument(document);

document = createTextDocument(10); // limit to 10 chars
textField2.setDocument(document);
```

Here is custom `TextDocument` class:

```
public class TextDocument extends PlainDocument{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int maxLength = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    TextDocument(){}
    TextDocument(int maxlength){this.maxLength=maxlength;}

     public void setMaxLength(int maxLength) {
            if (maxLength < 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxLength<0");
            this.maxLength = maxLength;
        }

     public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr)
     throws BadLocationException {
         if (validateLength(offset, str) == false)
                return;

            super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
     }

     private boolean validateLength(int offset, String toAdd) {
            String str_temp;
            //String str_text = "";
            String str1 = "";
            String str2 = "";
            try {
                str1 = getText(0, offset);
                str2 = getText(offset, getLength() - offset);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            str_temp = str1 + toAdd + str2;
            if (maxLength < str_temp.length()) {
                beep();
                return false;
            } else
                return true;

        }

        private void beep() {
            java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: thanks for the response.. but my problem still exist I'm trying to limit the 2 Jtextfield with different char limit but at the same time it doesnt accept white space as its first char

Comment: see my example, you use `TextDocument` just provide 5 and 10

Comment: about empty space in beginning, just change my class in `validateLength` method. very simple

Comment: I just figured it out.. I just put the condition on my code to your code... Sorry and thanks because I'm not yet familiar on the filtering and limiting..

Comment: Don't use a custom Document, use a DocumentFilter as has already been suggested in your last posting. The API has evolved over time and you can create more reusable code when using DocumentFilters.

Comment: @camickr Thanks,  in my project I used `static `Document` Factory with list of methods like: `createDoubleDocument` , `createIntDocument` ....

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the complication of using a Document by overriding the keyTyped event for each JTextField:

```
txtGuess = new JTextField();
txtGuess.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { 
        if (txtGuess.getText().length() >= 3 ) // limit textfield to 3 characters
            e.consume(); 
    }  
});
```

This limits the number of characters in a guessing game text field to 3 characters, by overriding the keyTyped event and checking to see if the textfield already has 3 characters - if so, you're "consuming" the key event (e) so that it doesn't get processed like normal.

Hope it's of help.